# Do questions about the functions of a game system itself fit here or in the SuperUser stack exchange?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions, gaming-hardware

I posted a question about how the 360 and X-box Live manage installations which involve DLC, how to successfully ensure they are installed to external media with all content so they are playable, etc.  It occurred to me that while this question is about gaming, it's about the hardware, X-Box OS, and X-Box Live. As such, its flavor is a little different from most questions in Arqade and views are very low vs similarly recent questions.  Did I put this in the right place, or is this something that I should have put in SuperUser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[What topics can I ask about here?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

> Arqade is for passionate videogamers from all platforms, including consoles, computers, handhelds, and mobile devices. If your question generally covers things such as …
>
> - Gameplay strategies and tactics
> - Puzzle solving or obstacle clearing
> - Game mechanics and terminology
> - Plot and characters in games
> - **Game-specific hardware and utilities**
>
> …then you are in the right place to ask your question!

Yes, gaming consoles are on-topic.